# Expressing $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{2}} \left \lfloor x^{1/n}-1 \right \rfloor$ in terms of the nontrivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series, analytic-number-theory

Let $\left \lfloor \cdot \right \rfloor$ be the floor function. Is there a way to express the function $A(x)$ given by :
$$A(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{2}} \left \lfloor x^{1/n}-1 \right \rfloor\;\;\;\;\; (x \geqslant 2)$$

in terms of the nontrivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function?

The motivation behind the question is that there is a somewhat similar situation with [the second Chebyshev function $\psi(x)$][1], where we have the formula:
$$\log\left(\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor !\right )=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\psi\left(\frac{x}{n} \right )$$
and by Möbius inversion, we have :
$$\psi(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(n)\log\left(\left \lfloor \frac{x}{n} \right \rfloor !\right )=x-\sum_{\rho}\frac{x^{\rho}}{\rho}-\log(2\pi)-\frac{1}{2}\log(1-x^{-2})$$
So, on the LHS we have a summation in terms of a trivial number-theoretic function - $\log\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor !$ - that terminates at a finite $n$, and on the RHS we have a Fourier series in terms of the nontrivial zeros of zeta.

**My attempt:**

We won't deal with the smooth part of $A(x)$, as it's quite easy to obtain. The oscillatory part is given by:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{2}}\left \{ x^{1/n} \right \}$$
For convenience,  we replace f(x) by the function $g(x)$:
$$g(x)=f\left(e^{x}\right)-\frac{3}{\pi^{2}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{2}}p\left(e^{x/n}\right)$$
where $p(\cdot)$ is the sawtooth function, which has the Fourier expansion :
$$p\left(e^{x/n}\right)=-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi i m}\left(\exp(2\pi i me^{x/n} )-\exp(-2\pi i me^{x/n} )\right)$$$$=-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi i m}\left(\exp\left(2\pi i m\left(e^{x/n}-1\right)\right) -\exp\left(-2\pi i m\left(e^{x/n}-1\right)\right) \right)$$
Assuming we can reverse the order of the summation - i have no proof! - we have that :
$$g(x)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\phi(m,x)}{m}$$
where we define :
$$\phi(m,x)=-\frac{1}{2\pi i }\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{2}}\left(\exp\left(2\pi i m\left(e^{x/n}-1\right)\right) -\exp\left(-2\pi i m\left(e^{x/n}-1\right)\right) \right)$$

Using the generating function of the [Touchard polynomials][2] $T_{k}(\cdot)$, we have :
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\left(\exp\left(2\pi i m\left(e^{x/n}-1\right)\right) -\exp\left(-2\pi i m\left(e^{x/n}-1\right)\right) \right)=\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\tilde{T}_{k}(2\pi m)}{k!}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^{k}$$
Where we define :
$$\tilde{T}_{k}(2\pi m)=\frac{1}{2i}\left(T_{k}(2\pi i m)-T_{k}(-2\pi i m)\right)=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2\pi m)^{l}}{l!}l^{k}\sin\left(\frac{\pi l}{2}\right)$$
Thus :
$$\phi(m,x)=-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\tilde{T}_{k}(2\pi m)}{\zeta(k+2)k!}x^{k}=-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}\tilde{T}_{k}(2\pi m)}{\zeta(k+2)k!}(-x)^{k}$$
Making use of Ramanujan's master theorem, we have for some vertical strip in the complex $s$ plane :
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\phi(x,m)x^{s-1}dx=-\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\Gamma(s)G_{m}(s)}{\zeta(2-s)}$$
where we define the Dirichlet-Taylor series :
$$G_{m}(s)=(-1)^{-s}\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2\pi m)^{l}}{l^{s}l!}\sin\left(\frac{\pi l }{2}\right)$$
Now, by Millin inversion theorem, we have :
$$\phi(m,x)=-\frac{1}{2\pi^{2} i }\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}\frac{\Gamma(s)G_{m}(s)}{\zeta(2-s)}x^{-s}ds$$
The function $G_{m}(s)$ is clearly holomorphic. and if one shifts the path of integration properly, the contributions to the resulting series come only from the nontrivial zeros of $\zeta(2-s)$

Is this line of thought legit?
[1]: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MangoldtFunction.html
[2]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials

Comment: Yes, i know. But how to relate $e^{-z}$ to $p(e^{x})$ ? Possibly through some integral transform of the form $p(e^{x})=\int_{D}K(x, z)e^{-z}dz$ !?

Comment: I missed the floor. For $\Re(s)>1$, $\int_0^\infty \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2} \lfloor x^{1/n}\rfloor x^{-s-1}dx= \frac1s 
\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2} \zeta(ns)$

Comment: It seems to me $\Pi(x)=\sum\limits_2^x\frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log(n)}$ is more analogous to $\psi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x\Lambda(n)$ than your definition of $A(x)$. The explicit formula for $\Pi_o(x)=\underset{\epsilon\to 0}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{2} (\Pi(x-\epsilon)+\Pi(x+\epsilon))\right)$ is $\Pi_o(x)=\text{li}(x)-\sum\limits_\rho \text{Ei}\left(\rho \log(x)\right)-\log(2)-\sum\limits_n \text{Ei}(-2 n \log (x))$ which is equivalent to $\Pi_o(x)=\text{li}(x)-\sum\limits_\rho \text{Ei}\left(\rho \log(x)\right)-\log(2)+\int\limits_x^\infty \frac{1}{t \left(t^2-1\right) \log(t)}\,dt$.

Comment: @StevenClark it might be the case. But i'm not interested in the arithmetical significance of $A(x)$, but rather in its Fourier expansion in terms of the nontrivial zeros of zeta (if exists).

Comment: Why $\left\lfloor x^{1/n}-1 \right\rfloor$ versus $\left\lfloor x^{1/n} \right\rfloor$? Also, I don't believe $\frac1s  \sum\limits_{n\ge 1}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2} \zeta(ns)$ from the comment by user @reuns above has any non-trivial poles.

Comment: The former has the advantage that it terminates at a finite $n$. So it's easier to compute. And we can recover the later simply by adding $6/\pi^{2}$.

Comment: $\psi(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x}\Lambda(n)$ terminates at a finite $n$, but I don't believe $A(x)$ terminates at a finite $n$ in the interval $0<x<1$.

Comment: That's true, it doesn't.

Comment: So perhaps you need to define your function as $B(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0<x<2 \\
 A(x) & 2\leq x \\
\end{array}\right.$ where $A(x)$ only needs to be evaluated for $n\le \log_2(x)$.

Comment: The function looks similar to [RiemannR](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RiemannR.html)

Comment: @TymaGaidash. In what sense is it similar?

Comment: @MohammadAlJamal Your function:$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{2}}\left \{ x^{1/n} \right \}$ vs $\text{RiemannR}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)\text{li}(x^\frac1n)}{n}$ with [li](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogIntegral.html). They may have similar properties.